# Add User Edit and Profile pages to Quicktabs

Tags: blocks

I'm using the module Quicktabs on my user pages.

[image: Double Tabs]

As you can see here I now have 2 rows of tabs and would like to move the User Edit and Profile to the Quicktabs tabs.  However the options of block, view, node, qtabs and callback don't seem to cover these pages.

Has anyone else got around this problem.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I create my quicktabs programmatically most of the tines exactly to avoid this kind of problems and expedients.

You need to choose 'callback' for both tabs, and use 'user/x' for profile and 'user/x/edit' for the form.

What x is?

the user uid, but since you need it to change based on the current user, you need to take it from the path the tabs will be displayed on.

assuming the path is

```
"mysite/candidate/{user uid}/dashboard"
```

replace x with %2 (or %3).

you don't have the uid in your path?

then create the quicktab programmatically :)

Comment: Hi 

Thanks for the reply.  Unfortunately I haven't got the user id in the URL .  i guess it'll be coming from $user on the page I have the tabs.  I'll look in to doing it programmatically later today.

Comment: Getting the user uid with %NO worked for me, in my case I needed to add that tab in the user profile page that is user/{uid}/edit. So creating a quicktab callback and using user/%1/edit as the path worked like a charm!!